# spring batch: multiple readers one processor, sequential processing

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a reader that reads from a datasource, a processor, and writer in spring batch.

Now I have a situation where i need to read from two datasource and send it to the single processor? I tried creating my own `ItemStreamReader` but it runs in parallel and it gives me result set closed exception when the two datasource returns different length result size.

How can this be achieved? Any help is appreciated.

thanks
Sanjeev

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about the data?  Specifically, does one query drive the results of the other or are they completely independent?

Comment: its two different datasource: one connects to oracle, the other connects to sql server but there must be a single processor where the results go to.

Comment: I meant about the relationship between the data in Oracle and the data in SqlServer.

Comment: these data are similar. its two application that saves data to oracle and sql server. And the batch should combine them together, processes it and writes it to a file to send it to a third party vendor for processing. the processing logic is same for data coming  from both.

Comment: You really need to provide more information on what your trying.... is your data to be partly read from the first source and then partly ready from the next?
Have you tried http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html